# Add icons to link_to in js.erb.html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

How can I add `<i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>` to a `link_to` helper?

```
$('.like_song').bind('ajax:success', function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.vote_count').html('<%= escape_javascript @song.votes_for.size.to_s %>');
  $(this).closest('.like_song').hide();
  $(this).closest('.votes').html(' <%= link_to "Unfavorite", unlike_song_path(@song), remote: true, method: :get, class: 'unlike_song' %>');
});
```

What I'm trying to do is to create an icon (button) for favorite/unfavorite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it passing it in a block, like `<%= link_to path, options do %> ... <% end %>`, where ... is where you can add the i tag, in your case:

```
<%= link_to unlike_song_path(@song), remote: true, method: :get, class: 'unlike_song' do %>
  <i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i>
<% end %>
```

Note as "Unfavorite" is what was inside your a tags, now isn't needed, the content inside the tags is the `i` icon.

Comment: Thank you! This works! But I'm having problems with user favorting song.. Once I click on the icon, icon changes from 'fa fa-heart-o' to 'fa fa-heart'.. bu when I refresh the page it reverts to empty heart. Is there an option user can favorite song once, so the icon heart stays populated?  I'm using act_as_votable gem for this.. thanks for the help

Comment: Maybe you're updating with the same content of both actions, when marking as favorite and unfavorite, take a look, if isn't, then, add your code to know a little bit more your scenario.

Comment: Here is my code here : https://repl.it/Ktfc  Thank you! Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Thanks...Tried it, but still need to refresh the page to get it unfavorited :(

Comment: let me know if you can't acces it https://bitbucket.org/Admir23/favplay